# How to use NJ tree reconstruction in heatmap.2?

Tags: r, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering

I'm using heatmap.2() function from gplots R package, which is a wonderfull function.

This function uses hlcust to construct tree to re-order data. My problem is that hclust can't use Neighbor-Joining method to construct the tree.

My question is, how I can use Nj algorithm with heatmap.2 function.

I tried heatmap.2( hclustfun = function(x) nj(x) ) with nj() is a function from package ape to compute NJ tree,  but I have the following issue:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.dendrogram") : 
  pas de méthode pour 'as.dendrogram' applicable pour un objet de classe "phylo"
```

How I can get a dendogram object from nj() function that can be given to heatmap.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, I found a solution here :

http://www.polarmicrobes.org/merging-a-phylogenetic-tree-with-a-heatmap-in-r/

It seems to work on my data